# Remove Guest account access to terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, user-management

I want to lock down the guest account so they cannot launch the terminal application. I know they don't have sudo access but I don't want them to be able to launch terminal at all. the users do not need access to it.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2240514&s=64cd1e4bef6b0c5f997ce28dc2e31171&p=13103526#post13103526

Comment: Is this the default Ubuntu guest account or one you created?

Answer (score 0):

For example for `gnome-terminal`, do

```
$ which gnome-terminal
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal

$ sudo chmod o-x /usr/bin/gnome-terminal

$ gpasswd -d guest root
```

This will remove the execution permission for other users as the file owner (root) and `root` group members and remove `guest` from the `root` group.